# Encrypt .ini file

Tags: c#, encryption, ini

How could i encrypt .ini file and read data from the app while it's encrypted?
iam using that could to read

```
public string ReadString(string Section, string Key)
        {
            return this.ReadString(Section, Key, "", 400);
        }
```

Comment: Well, how do you want to encrypt it? And how long are you prepared to have it in memory decrypted? I expect that as soon as anybody answers, loads more constraints will appear.

Comment: by any way i just want to hide mysql user and password from normal users

Comment: It sounds like you just want to encrypt those values. In which case this is not about ini files and is about encrypting strings.

Comment: the file had another important information also that i want to keep it save so i hope to encrypt the whole file instead of each string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can use this to encrypt any text or file
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/769741/csharp-aes-bits-encryption-library-with-salt